# Missing VC 2008 Runtime redistributable package not found

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, windows-7-x64

I downloaded eclipse and installed the BlackBerry plugin for eclipse.

Now when I start eclipse:

> Missing Visual C++ 2008 Runtime redistributable package not found. The reguired package can be installed from: [MS VS2008 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29).

I download/install/(also restart PC) it from the given url, but the warning is still shown when I start eclipse.

P.S I'm using Windows 7 x64 
P.S Also I tried MS VS2008 for x64 but the warning is still shown on startup.

Comment: the link you posted in for 32-bit Windows. Download 64-bit version instead.

Comment: Thank you. But I downlod x64 too. The same.

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit version of eclipse? The blackberry plugin doesn't work on the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from using 64-bit Eclipse.

Blackberry Java plugin for Eclipse requires 32 bit Java/Eclipse to function properly, according to these KB articles -

- [Supported versions of Java for different BlackBerry JDE versions](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Supported-versions-of-Java-for-different-BlackBerry-JDE-versions/ta-p/446034)
- [Error when debugging: Cannot find RIMIDEWin32Util.dll. This is a required component of the IDE.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Error-when-debugging-Cannot-find-RIMIDEWin32Util-dll-This-is-a/ta-p/444928)

You *can* configure a 64 bit Eclipse to work with Blackberry Java using some ad-hockery, but you won't be able to debug properly because of the problem mentioned in the second KB article. It's best to use a 32 bit version of Eclipse instead.

Comment: I will award this answer because it's the only one and probably the only reasonable one, although the problem is not 100% solved by installing the 32bit Java/Eclipse. Still some problems remain.

Comment: @castle1971 Can you mention what problems are you encountering? I'm running Juno with Blackberry Java plug-in on a 64 bit machine and I haven't come across any problems yet.

Comment: Thats right. The problem comes from using 64-bit Eclipse for BlackBerry.